# How to split the words in one column then integrate the words together in Python, i.e., two dimensional list to one dimensional list?

Tags: string, pandas, list, split

My data is:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'sentences':['i am here','bye bye','go back home quickly']})
```

When I use split, I can transfer the strings into individual words:

```
a.loc[:,'sentences1']=a.loc[:,'sentences'].astype(str).str.split(' ')
```

The result is:

```
              sentences                 sentences1
0             i am here              [i, am, here]
1               bye bye                 [bye, bye]
2  go back home quickly  [go, back, home, quickly]
```

Now, I want to integrate the lists in the columns 'sentences1' then delete the duplicates. So it would look like:

```
[i, am, here, bye, go, back, home, quickly]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to flatten the list of list with `dict.keys` to remove dupes and maintain order:

```
import itertools
[*itertools.chain.from_iterable([dict.fromkeys(i.split()).keys() for i in a.sentences])]
```

Or use `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
[*itertools.chain.from_iterable([OrderedDict.fromkeys(i.split()).keys() 
                                                for i in a.sentences])]
```

---

```
['i', 'am', 'here', 'bye', 'go', 'back', 'home', 'quickly']
```

Comment: Cool!, Thanks a lot.